# Setear el valor de una clase me genera un NullPointer - Java

Tags: java, clase

Buenas estoy realizando el siguiente ejercicio en el cual me piden dos metodos :

**Crear una clase llamada Maquina de Dulces cuyos atributos sea Celda1 : de tipo Celda, asi hasta la Celda4 y un saldo de tipo de double**

- Un metodo llamado configurarMaquina que recibe 4 codigos de celda de
  tipo String, no retorna nada y los asigna a cada una de las celdas de
  la maquina
- Un metodo mostrarConfiguracion que no recibe parametros y    no tiene
  retorno, imprime en consola los codigos de las 4 celdas.

Por lo que tengo entendido tendria que tratar a la Clase Celda como un tipo de dato mas y eso hice(creo):

**CLASE CELDA**

```
package com.clearminds.componentes;

public class Celda {
Producto producto;
private int stock;
private String codigo;

public Celda(String codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

public String getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}
```

}

**CLASE MAQUINA DE DULCES**

```
package com.clearminds.maquina;

import com.clearminds.componentes.Celda;
import com.clearminds.componentes.Producto;

public class MaquinasDulces {
private Celda celda1;
private Celda celda2;
private Celda celda3;
private Celda celda4;
private double saldo;



public void configurarMaquina(String cod1,String cod2,String cod3,String cod4){
   celda1.setCodigo(cod1);
   celda2.setCodigo(cod2);
   celda3.setCodigo(cod3);
   celda4.setCodigo(cod4);
}

public void mostrarConfiguracion(){
    System.out.println("Celda: " + this.celda1.getCodigo());
    System.out.println("Celda: " + this.celda2.getCodigo());
    System.out.println("Celda: " + this.celda3.getCodigo());
    System.out.println("Celda: " + this.celda4.getCodigo());
    System.out.println("Saldo: " + saldo);
}

}
```

**EN EL MAIN**

```
package com.clearminds.test;

import com.clearminds.maquina.MaquinasDulces;

public class TestConfiguracion {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MaquinasDulces maquina=new MaquinasDulces();
    maquina.configurarMaquina("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2");

    maquina.mostrarConfiguracion();

}

}
```

**ERROR**
*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.clearminds.maquina.MaquinasDulces.configurarMaquina(MaquinasDulces.java:55)
at com.clearminds.test.TestConfiguracion.main(TestConfiguracion.java:9)*

De verdad no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal. Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Lo mejor es que creas una lista de ``Celda`` como atributo en tu clase ``MaquinaDulces`` , luego inicializas en el constructor como ``new ArrayList<Celdas>``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso pasa por que llamas el metodo  configurarMaquina setteando los valores en las celdas, pero estas celdas aun no existen , no las has creado . Podrias crear un constructor en MaquinasDulces que las inicialice. Algo como esto :

```java
package com.clearminds.maquina;

import com.clearminds.componentes.Celda;
import com.clearminds.componentes.Producto;

public class MaquinasDulces {
private Celda celda1;
private Celda celda2;
private Celda celda3;
private Celda celda4;
private double saldo;

public MaquinasDulces(){
   celda1 = new Celda(""); // Adiciono las commillas por que tu constructot pide un string
   celda2 = new Celda("");
   celda3 = new Celda("");
   celda4 = new Celda("");
}

public void configurarMaquina(String cod1,String cod2,String cod3,String cod4){
   celda1.setCodigo(cod1);
   celda2.setCodigo(cod2);
   celda3.setCodigo(cod3);
   celda4.setCodigo(cod4);
}

public void mostrarConfiguracion(){
    System.out.println("Celda: " + this.celda1.getCodigo());
    System.out.println("Celda: " + this.celda2.getCodigo());
    System.out.println("Celda: " + this.celda3.getCodigo());
    System.out.println("Celda: " + this.celda4.getCodigo());
    System.out.println("Saldo: " + saldo);
}

}
```

Pdta : El codigo se puede mejorar si haces una lista de celdas y no declaras cada una.

```
  List<Celda> celdas = new ArrayList<Celdas>
```

con esto  puedes agregar las celdas que quieras

Comment: Uff. ¿Enserio me tardó 12min escribir la respuesta? Que gane el mejor entonces. Suerte.

Comment: Muchas gracias ,efectivamente me sirvio lo que tu dices del constructor.

Answer (score 2):

El error que obtienes se da porque intentas acceder a una variable sin definir o que actualmente está establecida en `null`. El caso es que las variables primitivas no definidas se asignan en `0` por defecto y las que usan una clase de tipo se establecen en `null`.

Fíjate, que en la clase `MaquinaDulces`, en ningún momento defines las variables de  `Celda`.

Puedes solucionarlo con las siguientes líneas de código:

```
celda1 = new Celda(); 
celda2 = new Celda();
celda3 = new Celda();
celda4 = new Celda();
```

Si lo tanscribes ahora mismo tendrás un error porque la clase `Celda` no tiene un constructor sin parámetros. Puedes optar por agregar uno:

```
public Celda(){}
```

o pasarle una cadena cualquiera, vacía incluso y usar el que ya tienes. Así: `new Celda("")`.

Está inicialización la puedes llevar a cabo en el constructor de `MaquinaDulces`:

```
public MaquinaDulces(){
    celda1 = new Celda(); 
    celda2 = new Celda();
    celda3 = new Celda();
    celda4 = new Celda();
}
```

Posiblemente te preguntes por qué tienes que definir un constructor sin parámetros para `Celda` si antes usabas `MaquinaDulces` sin tener uno. Es porque si tu no defines ningún constructor en una clase, el propio Java hará uno por defecto, de lo contrario no podrías crear instancias. En cambio, cuando se define un constructor, Java no crea ese constructor.

Comment: Lastima que no se puede dar el chulito verde a todos las respuesta ni tampoco tengo suficiente puntos para dartelo a ti pero tu respuesta mee sirvio un monton. Muchas gracias, ya hice lo del constructor yme funciono al toque

Comment: De nada. Puedes ver qué ambos pensamos más o menos en lo mismo. Sobre el tick verde, queda a tu criterio decidir cuál es la respuesta que te resultó más útil o mejor te ayudó. Lastimosamente solo se puede escoger una.